# how to wrap a component content with html tag dynamically in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Hi i want to wrap the content of a component with some specific html tag let say `button` for this example.

i have a function which dynamically returns a value which i use as a prop, based on that i want to wrap the content of a component.

i know i could have achieved this way too `<button><compA/></button>` it does not solve my problem beacuse i need to change it in 100 places.

**My expected result:**

1. `<button><div>press me i'm button</div></button>`
2. `<div>don't wrap me with button leave me as it is</div>`

**Note:** `:wrappwithbutton=""` having `true` for 1st usage and `false` for 2nd usage

```js
const localComponent = {
     name:'first-comp',
     template:`<div> {{text}}</div>`,
     props:['wrappwithbutton','text'],
}



const app = new Vue({
   el:'#app',
   name:'app',
  components:{'first-comp':localComponent},
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


  <div id="app">

    <first-comp :wrappwithbutton="true" text="press me i'm button"></first-comp>
    
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <br/>
    
       <first-comp :wrappwithbutton="false" text="don't wrap me with button leave me as it is"></first-comp>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect example for render functions. Instead of using a template you can use a render function to render the template for you. [Read more about render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)

```js
const localComponent = {
 name:'first-comp',
 props:['wrappwithbutton', 'text'],
 methods: {
   btnClick() {
     if (this.wrappwithbutton) console.log('button')
   }
 },
 render(h) {
   return h(this.wrappwithbutton ? 'button' : 'div', [
     h('div', this.text)
   ])
 }
}

const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  name:'app',
  components:{'first-comp':localComponent},
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

You can even go a step further and make your `localComponent` to be more dynamic with the parent passing a prop with the tag that should be rendered:

```js
const localComponent = {
 name:'first-comp',
 props:['tag', 'text'],
 methods: {
   btnClick() {
     if (this.wrappwithbutton) console.log('button')
   }
 },
 render(h) {
   return h(this.tag, [
     h('div', this.text)
   ])
 }
}
```

If you would like to have a single `div` and not two `divs` you can do:

```
render(h) {
   if (this.tag === 'div') {
     return ('div', this.text);
   }

   return h(this.tag ? 'button' : 'div', [
     h('div', this.text)
   ])
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but in this case `div` will be wrapped by another `div`

Comment: @Radeanu Edited the answer to reflect the solution to your comment

Comment: yes that's perfect

Comment: this is what i was expecting great solution !! 1 doubt i have let say i don't want to do anything in `render` but `render` expect to return something in that case what would i return `return h`  that would sufficient

Comment: @EaBengaluru I'm not currently on my computer but I think you can just return `null`. `render(h) { return null; }` and Vue will sort that out for oyu

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea, but I think the template should have a more concise way of writing

```js
const localComponent = {
  name: "first-comp",
  template: `
    <template v-if="wrappwithbutton">
      <button>
        <div> {{text}}</div>
      </button>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <div> {{text}}</div>
    </template>
  `,
  props: ["wrappwithbutton", "text"]
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: "app",
  components: { "first-comp": localComponent }
});
```